# Set variable on mouseover

Tags: asp.net, variables, razor, set, mouseover

everyone. Long time lurker, first time poster =)

First of thanks in advance for anyone reading my issue and considering to help me out. I will be specific on what it is I am trying to do as I cant just ask someone to fix my code.

I have a webpage that displays our open projects in a thumbs style view across the page. Each project is in it's own container div. Each container holds a snapshot image thumb of the first page of the project and that image is set to float to the left giving a strip of space left in the div on the right. This space on the right has 5 icons going down the side of the image. Each icon represents, project leader, members, department, and status.

Thats the layout. This is an ASP.NET MVC Razor cshtml website, so each project has a model holding the info for each project (project.Id, project.Leader, project.Crew, etc). My goal is to be able to hover over each icon and have it display the info for that icon.

The trouble i am running into is when I hover over the icons and it calls for the @project.Leader, it does not know WHICH project I am asking for its leader. So I was thinking the best way would be to have it set the id of the div to a variable when i hover over the "container div" for that project, so that when i hover over the icon i can use the variable to tell it WHICH project i am calling the project.Leader for.

I hope this makes sense =) ANY ideas would be of great help, but please understand I am not a native coder so I can get confused easy.

Thanks everyone for reading!!!! =)

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can just get parent of the element being clicked:

```
$(".project-icon").hover(function() {
    var target = $(this);
    var container = target.parent();

    // You can use a class on the image to get it from the parent container:
    var image = container.find(".project-image");

    // Or you can get the container's id:
    var id = container.attr("id");
});
```

You can do this with plain javascript of course but then you are left with the task of making sure your code works everywhere.  Toolkits like jQuery take care of these details for you.  They come hightly recommended by everyone who does the sort of thing you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, Michael!!! I will certainly use jQuery if that is best. I dont fully understand the code, even thought you seem to have been very descriptive. Where is .project-icon and .project-image coming from?

I understand the code for the most part tho =) I will see if i can google how u got those names =)

Comment: Well, Thanks for the info, Michale... but unfortunately I don't understand your code at all. The adding of .project-icon & .project-image has completely thrown me. I am lost.